# Difference in two array deletion code

Tags: java, arrays

I have these two code for the deletion of an element from an array ,but there is just one difference the these two for loops  `for(int k=i;k< l-1;k++)`
and  `for(int k =i;k< l;k++)` in first we are de-crementing the size of the length of an array but in second we are not. Both the code are same else and does its deletion job fine. But I couldn't get the difference.

1st

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class SearchDeletion1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int []a = new int[10];
            a[0]=33;
            a[1]=11;
            a[2]=22;
            a[3]=333;
            a[4]=343;
            a[5]=233;
            a[6]=373;
            a[7]=3223;
            a[8]=313;
            a[9]=332;
            int i;
            System.out.println();
            int l=a.length;
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the item to be searched");
            int e = s.nextInt();
            //searching
            for(i=0;i<l;i++)
                if(a[i]==e)
                break;
                if(i==a.length)
                    System.out.println("couldn't found");
                else 
                    System.out.println("found at position "+"a["+i+"]");

            //deleting
                for(int k=i;k<l-1;k++)
                    a[k]=a[k+1]; 
                     l--;
           System.out.println("item deleted and new array");
           for(int q=0;q<l;q++){
               System.out.println("a["+q+"]"+"="+a[q]);
           }
    }
    }
```

2nd

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SearchDeletion2 {
    private int a[] ;
    SearchDeletion2(int size){
     a =new int[size];
    }
    public void set(int index,int elem){
        a[index]=elem;
    }
    public int get(int index){
        return a[index];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SearchDeletion2 arr = new SearchDeletion2(100);
        arr.set(0,33);
        arr.set(1,22);
        arr.set(2,11);
        arr.set(3,99);
        arr.set(4,66);
        arr.set(5,44);
        arr.set(6,77);
        arr.set(7,88);
        arr.set(8,55);
        arr.set(9,112);
        int i;
        int l=10;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
            if(arr.get(i)==r)
                break;
        System.out.println(i);
        for(int k =i;k<l;k++)

            arr.set(k,arr.get(k+1));

             l--;
             System.out.println(l);
            for (int o=0;o<l;o++) 
                 System.out.println(arr.get(o));


            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your actual question?

Comment: You should try to post smaller chunks of code, only with the interesting part. See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second piece of code is wrong, because at the last iteration (with `k==l-1`) it performs `arr.get(k+1)`, which means `arr.get(l-1+1)`, which is `arr.get(l)`, which is an invalid index for an array of `l` elements (going from `0` to `l-1`).

The code doesn't break because the actual array is bigger than l (100 'slots' are allocated, against 10 actually used). Anyway, it isn't a code that is safe under all the possible circumstances. So you shouldn't use it.

PS: the code would actually be safe, if the `get` method was implemented to be somehow resilient to invalid indices. Such as:

```
public int get(int index){
    return (index < size) ? a[index] : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not increasing or decreasing the size of array at any point in this code. All you are doing is changing the variable l, which dictates how many elements you are going to traverse. So even if you changed the loop to `for(int k =i;k<l+10;k++)` it would behave in the same way unless you started accessing elements beyond the allocated 100 in which case you would get ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.